# Debezium Postgres sink connector fails to insert values with type DATE

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

After setting up both source and sink connectors, I get problems with `DATE` type Postgres columns.

> ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer

I checked Avro schema and see that column `foo` was serialized as `io.debezium.time.Date`

```
{
    "default": null,
    "name": "foo",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Date",
            "connect.version": 1,
            "type": "int"
        }
    ]
}
```

What should I do to let sink connector insert this values correctly (as `DATE`, not `INTEGER`)?

**Full stacktrace:**

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id","foo") VALUES (75046,18577) ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "foo"=EXCLUDED."foo" was aborted: ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 249  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 249
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 249

    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id","foo") VALUES (75046,18577) ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "foo"=EXCLUDED."foo" was aborted: ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 249  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 249
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "foo" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 249

    ... 12 more
```

**Source config:**

```
{
    "name": "dbz-source-test-1",
    "config": {
        "name":"dbz-source-test-1",
        "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname":"some.host",
        "database.port":"5432",
        "database.user":"test_debezium",
        "database.password":"password",
        "database.dbname":"dbname",
        "plugin.name":"wal2json_rds",
        "slot.name":"wal2json_rds",
        "database.server.name":"server_test",
        "table.whitelist":"public.test_table",
        "transforms":"route",
        "transforms.route.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.route.regex":"([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.route.replacement":"dbz_source_$3",
        "topic.selection.strategy":"topic_per_table",
        "include.unknown.datatypes":true,
        "decimal.handling.mode":"double",
        "snapshot.mode":"never"
    }
}
```

**Sink config:**

```
{
    "name": "dbz-sink-test-1",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "config.providers" : "file",
        "config.providers.file.class" : "org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider",
        "config.providers.file.param.secrets" : "/opt/mysecrets",
        "topics": "dbz_source_test_table",
        "connection.url": "someurl",
        "connection.user": "${file:/opt/mysecrets.properties:user}",
        "connection.password" : "${file:/opt/mysecrets.properties:pass}",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
        "table.name.format": "dbz_source_",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.field": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the entire stacktrace? Does it occur in Debezium or the sink connector? Things should also work with the default time precision mode, so there might be a bug here somewhere.

Comment: @Gunnar exception in connector itself, updating question with stacktrace and connectors config

Comment: Ok, thanks. How did you create the table schema on the sink side? If you manually created it and set the column type to `DATE`, that behavior is to be expected, as the JDBC sink connector doesn't know how to convert the incoming int value into that column type. Using the `connect` type mapping is the right way then; alternatively, you could use an SMT to convert the incoming int into the right type yourself.

Comment: @Gunnar yes, you're right, I created schema manually and column type is `DATE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed problem switching source connector [`time.precision.mode` config to `connect`](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.10/connectors/postgresql.html)

> When the time.precision.mode configuration property is set to connect, then the connector will use the predefined Kafka Connect logical types. This may be useful when consumers only know about the built-in Kafka Connect logical types and are unable to handle variable-precision time values.

After it serialization type becomes different:

```
{
    "default": null,
    "name": "foo",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date",
            "connect.version": 1,
            "logicalType": "date",
            "type": "int"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sink connector is aware of `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date` type and inserts in correctly.

Comment: Wow, this took me a long time to find, great job!

Comment: The only thing is that with this option there is a problem when timestamp column has value of +infinity/-infinity on sink side propably.